# How to iterate through the digits of a number without having it under the form of a string in Python?

Tags: python, iteration

I've seen a couple posts explaning how to iterate through the digits of a number in Python, but they all turn the number into a string before iterating through it... 
For example:

```
n=578
print d for d in str(n)
```

How can I do this without the conversion into a string?

Comment: This question would be better if you provided an example of what you mean. You’ll have a much better chance of getting good answers if you [edit] your question to be clearer, show some of the research you’ve done, what you’ve tried, etc. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`10**int(log(n, 10))` is basically `10*`, such that it is the same length as `n`.  The floor division of n by that will give us the leading digit, while the modulo `%` gives us the rest of the number.

```
from math import log

def digits(n):
    if n < 0:
        yield '-'
        n = -1 * n
    elif n == 0:
        yield 0
        return
    xp = int(log(n, 10).real)
    factor = 10**xp
    while n:
        yield int(n/factor)
        n = n % factor
        try:
            xp, old_xp = int(log(n, 10).real), xp
        except ValueError:
            for _ in range(xp):
                yield 0
            return
        factor = 10**xp
        for _ in range(1, old_xp-xp):
            yield 0

for x in digits(12345):
    print(x)
```

prints

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Edit: I switched to this version, which is much less readable, but more robust.  This version correctly handles negative and zero values, as well as trailing and internal `0` digits.